# Should I use a Pivot Table or a new table - Entity Supplied

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I am seeking advice, so that i move forward in the right direction.

I am implementing the Party relationship Model in MySQL.

Parties can be people or organisations and can have many contacts and many addresses.

There are different types of Parties: Customers, Suppliers, Agents, Users   etc…

What is the most efficient way to represent this in a database. Im using MySQL and Postgres.

I have attached an example the entity relationship to illustrate my choices.

[image: party relationship]

Comment: You would need a pivot as a Party could be a Customer and a Supplier.

Comment: http://imgur.com/QYpdJyK